# How to reffer to an interface from within an anonymous class in Android?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have the following class:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements Observer<List<User>>
```

And

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {return false;}

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchText) {
        if (searchText.length() > 0) {
            myLiveData.removeObservers(getViewLifecycleOwner(), this);
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

To the `removeObservers()` function I need to pass a `LifecycleOwner` object as the first argument (which works) and as the second argument on `Oberver` object. When using the above line of code, it fails because of the second `this` is **not** referring the interface that is implemented in the fragment. How to make `this` point to the right interface and get the corresponding `Oberver` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyFragment.this` is what you are looking for